# Why do the leaves of my avocado tree have brown edges and spots?

Tags: fruit-trees, watering, avocado

I have inherited an avocado tree in a hot, arid climate in a very windy spot.

It has been watered well, but its leaves look like something is wrong with it - they have brown edges.

[image]

Perhaps it's been watered *too* well - the soil it's in appears to be a bit dense and loamy:

[image]

What should I do?

Should I try to loosen the soil manually?

Comment: If this picture is the actual tree then it might be a mango not an avocado

Comment: @mrsuthe Please explain why you think it's a mango, and what you would do to cure or prevent the brown edges on the leaves. As it stands, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen this same type of damage on an avocado in a pot that was allowed to go dry.

Given that your plant is outdoors in a hot and dry area this looks like stress caused by inadequate water.

Avocados require a well aerated soil with water that is low in dissolved salts.  A soil depth of 1 metre is helpful in maintaining water levels.

The recommendations [for California](http://www.californiaavocado.com/grow-your-own-avocado-tree/) are to apply a mulch of organic material at least two inches deep.  You could also topdress first with good soil.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is salt in your water. I had the same problem but when I changed  the water the tree started to look alive again: new branches, new leaves  and fruits.  You should also fertilize it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like wind damage to me, especially as the edges are browned and dry. The same can be seen if leaves on delicate shrubs like acers are exposed to wind.

Answer (score 1):

The leaves definitely look like a mango. Too much fertilizer or fertilizer not watered in well can also cause salt build up. Water less often but more deeply.